# "wakeup" doesn't work

Tags: software-recommendation, graphics, software-center

Everytime I hit "apply" it says "Unable to set all alarms. Check time preferences"

Whats this?

Can someone help fix this?

Or if any other alarm clock app exists which wakes the laptop from sleep to ring?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>**Note:** This answer applies to 12.04 where the version of the `wakeup` package is `1.2.x`. If you're having this problem on 12.10 (or later, this answer probably doesn't apply to you.</sub>

Sticking that error into Google would have alerted you to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/wakeup/+bug/990946

There's a rookie error in `/usr/bin/setalarm` that you can edit out or patch yourself (running the following command should do it):

```
sudo patch /usr/bin/setalarm <(<<EOF
 39,40c39
< cronstring = re.sub("\*", '"*"', cronstring)
< crontimes.append(re.sub('"', '', cronstring))
---
> crontimes.append(cronstring)
EOF)
```

Or you can [grab the a patched version from Launchpad and install that](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wakeup/+bug/990946/comments/17).

Comment: After I copy-paste your code into the terminal it asks for [sudo] password and after putting in my password (the same which unlocks the computer?) it says, "patch: **** Can't open patch file /dev/fd/63 : No such file or directory" What is this?